# what is allocator<T> in vectors and how to use it?

Tags: c++

This is my first time using allocator function in vectors and I came across the below code. I want to understand what exactly it is trying to do.

EDIT 
I have made changes suggested, When I run this below code I get an  error as below..why I am getting this ??

```
../../../../test_idct.cpp:38:62:   instantiated from here
/proj/xbuilds/2017.4_0206_1/installs/lin64/Vivado/2017.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stl_vector.h:206:20: error: no members matching ‘std::vector<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >}::_M_allocate’ in ‘std::vector<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >}’
/proj/xbuilds/2017.4_0206_1/installs/lin64/Vivado/2017.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stl_vector.h:207:20: error: no members matching ‘std::vector<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >}::_M_deallocate’ in ‘std::vector<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >}’
/proj/xbuilds/2017.4_0206_1/installs/lin64/Vivado/2017.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stl_vector.h:209:20: error: no members matching ‘std::vector<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >}::_M_get_Tp_allocator’ in ‘std::vector<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<short int, aligned_allocator<short int> >}’
../../../../test_idct.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
```

#### Code:

```
template <typename T>
struct aligned_allocator {
  typedef T value_type

  T* allocate(std::size_t num) {
    void* ptr = nullptr;
    if (posix_memalign(&ptr,4096,num*sizeof(T)))
      throw std::bad_alloc();
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
  }

  void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t num) {
    free(p);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int16_t,aligned_allocator<int16_t>> source_block(64*blocks);
  std::vector<uint16_t,aligned_allocator<uint16_t>> source_q(64);
  std::vector<int16_t,aligned_allocator<int16_t>> golden_vpout(64*blocks);
}
```

Comment: You aren't compiling as C++11. That's why you get those errors.

Comment: Note that this can be done in C++03, you just have to use the old-style type alias: `typedef T value_type;`

Comment: Wow, has implementing an allocator become so simple in C++11 and onwards? I still have to support C++03 at my workplace and am a bit behind, but we no longer need rebind, construct, destroy, address, etc? Just `allocate` and `deallocate` and a `value_type` alias and that's it?

Comment: @TeamUpvote: Yes, those are now optional, with fallback implementations provided by `allocator_traits`